# jqplot - how to display label with its value in legend?

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

Is it possible to show label with its value in legend?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it and more in `jqPlot`:

1. Easiest: Set `labels` element of `legend` to an array of Strings that will be displayed in your legend, [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/39/).
2. Do it yourself, as it is shown in the sample, [attached to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428650/613495). There I used `$.jqplot.postDrawHooks` to act when graph is finished, since I also needed to do some customization of the legend labels, so I went all the way (i.e. I didn't set the `labels` element).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="JqPloatChart/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
seriesDefaults: {renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,pointLabels: { show: true },rendererOptions: {showDataLabels: true,}},
```

Comment: Please add file of 
<script src="JqPloatChart/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script> and write render option in jqplot.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!