# jqplot group and label several data series with the same name and color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a matrix filled with six data series, where I would like to label the first five with the same name 'process a' (also give them the same color), and the left one with 'process b'. So is there a way to do this in jqplot? Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is the code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/300/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

        s1 = [[10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 14.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0], [10.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 16.0], [10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0], [10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0]];
        s2 = [10.0, 10.4, 10.816, 11.248640000000002, 11.698585600000003, 12.166529024000004];

        s1.push(s2);
        $.jqplot('chart1', s1, {

            seriesDefaults: { 
            showMarker:false,
             pointLabels: { show:false } ,
              },

            series:[
            {label:'Process A'},{label:'Process B'}
            ],

             legend: {
                  show: true,
                  location: 'nw',
                  placement: 'inside',
                fontSize: '11px'
            } 
        })   
    })​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. [I think this is what you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/JWhmQ/319/)
You already were on the right track. You just need to repeat setting of label and colour for each series accordingly, as in the code sample or below:

```
series:[
  {label:'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label:'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label:'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label:'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label:'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label:'Process B',color:'blue'}
]
```

---

**EDIT:**

[This is the answer where I show how to manipulate the legend.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10428650/613495)

Also please find this sample, extending the code of the other answer. [The sample shows how to hide legend with index 1.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/45/) Basically you grab swatches and labels and hide them using `jQuery`'s method `hide()`:

```
var swatches = $('table.jqplot-table-legend tr td.jqplot-table-legend-swatch');
var labels = $('table.jqplot-table-legend tr td.jqplot-table-legend-label');
$(swatches[1]).hide();
$(labels[1]).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is very close to what I would like. But is it possible to show only two legends (Process A and B) instead of all six (five Process A and one Process B)? In addition, is it possible to use a loop to assign those series information (use 'push' to add label names and colors)?

Comment: For your answer please see the **EDIT**.

Comment: There is an easier way to fix the multiple entries in the legend.  For the series configs add `showLabel: false` for each additional duplicate.  For example

`    series: [`
`        {label: 'Process A', color: 'red'}, {label: 'Process A', color: 'red', showLabel: false}`
`    ]`